# Require `FEATURE_RAM_NORMAL` on API 27 only, without creating multiple apks?

Tags: android, google-play, android-8.1-oreo

My application requires `NotificationListenerService` to work properly.

Starting with API 27, that means it will only work on devices with the feature `FEATURE_RAM_NORMAL`.

In theory I should use:

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.ram.normal"
    android:required="true" />
```

However, if I specify that feature as required, I am excluding all devices that came before API 27 and that don't have that feature in their configuration, because it was not available at the time.

Is there any way I can solve this issue without having to create multiple apks (hence, having multiple manifest files)?

PS: Do you think Google Play will add exclusions based on features to its Device Catalog (in this case, being able to exclude devices with feature `FEATURE_RAM_LOW`)?

Comment: This looks like a bug. Have you tried writing here : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues ?

Comment: I haven't, but I will. Thanks!

Comment: Please show here the new post, so that we could star it.

Comment: Issue posted: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/70607132